# Create co-occurrence matrix from edges of the graph

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, graph

I have graphs with parallels edges(more than one edges) as shown below

```
G=nx.read_edgelist('file.txt',create_using=nx.MultiGraph(), nodetype=int)
```

Example output
(`1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4), (1, 4)`

now here I want to create the co-occurrence matrix from this graph

example output

```
  1  2  3   4 
1 0  13 17  24
2 13 0
etc
```

How can i do so? Most of the solutions from stack overflow are for word co-occurrence

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Counter` from the `collections` module:

```
from collections import Counter

G = ...
cocounts = Counter(list(G.edges()))

# Then just allocate a list (2x4) or something and create the matrix:
res = [[0 for c in range(4)] for r in range(2)]
for cocount, count in cocounts.items():
    res[cocount[0]-1][cocount[1]-1] = count
```

Comment: Hi @Moosefeather, thank for your answer, i try to replicate it and i am getting this error, G =nx.read_edgelist('file.txt',create_using=nx.MultiGraph(), nodetype=int) nodes=list(G.nodes())                                                                                          
 cocounts = Counter(G) res = [[0 for c in range(len(nodes))] for r in range(len(nodes))] for cocount, count in cocounts.items():                                                    
       res[cocount[0]-1][cocount[1]-1] = count ..TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable –

Comment: @christinamuro I must be misunderstanding the type that `G` is. Is `G` a list of tuples, tuple of tuples, or something else (and what then)?

Comment: sorry @Moosefeather, G  is the list of edges from the graph

Comment: @christinamuro ok when looking into the documentation of `networkx` I think i've solved the problem, please let me know if the edit works. And in the future please be more specific regarding what libraries etc you're working with.

Comment: Thank you @moosefeather, i really appreciate, but i am still getting one error, here        res = [[0 for c in range(len(nodes)] for r in range(len(nodes)], gives "out of range error"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225515/discussion-between-moosefeather-and-christina-muro).